# UML use case diagram for note saving application

Tags: oop, uml, modeling, use-case

i'm new to system modeling and i have some problems expressing my ideas into diagrams especially into use case diagram because of the lack of dynamic interactions let say.
[image: use case diagram for note saving/showing]

precondition : user must be connected

**specifications**
user will be able to view all his notes(in the home page kinda).
user can check a specific note and modify it by changing its title or its body or both.
user can access create note from the home page.
he must add title and body and at least one tag.
user can access create tag from create note page and from the home page.
when saving and returning to the main page system should save the note into backend.
when creating a tag user must enter the label and specify the color.

**Questions:**
1- is this a valid use case diagram for it?

2- should i add an association between the backend and create note and create tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's not really a valid UC diagram. UCs are about added value. You started functional decomposition (like most people try when starting with UCs). A UC represents a single added value the system under consideration delivers to one of its actors. Here you have a note which for which you have CRUD. Unfortunately that already gives one a pain. Is the added value a general `Manage X` or is there a fundamental difference between `Show` and the editing? That depends on the context and there is no general answer to that. However, you do not describe steps you take (actions; like `enter xy`) or various scenarios (activities) as single use cases. You need to try to synthesize as much as possible in a single UC to show added values. This is difficult for techies.

As a rule of thumb: if your UC diagram resembles a spider web then your design is likely broken.

As always I recommend to read Bittner/Spence about use cases.

Comment: thank you for your help, i just didn't inderstand what did you mean by don't describe various scenarios as single use cases.

Comment: The goal of a UC is achieved in many ways. There is at minimum the "sunny day" scenario which is self explainig. Then you likely have a couple of failing/deviating paths you would describe in other (accordingly named) scenarios. Each of those will be represented by an activity holding the actions (steps) from begin to end.